# cryptic c++, help me undertand

Tags: c++

First weird piece:

```
struct rect { int   area;   int perimeter;  int max_side; }
int n=2;
rect* test= new rect*[n]; // why multiplication sign???
```

Second weird piece:

```
bool (*cmpf[])(rect_xywhf*, rect_xywhf*) = { 
    area, 
    perimeter, 
    max_side 
};

rect** testarray[10];
std::sort(testarray[0], testarray[9], cmpf[0]);
```

I understand cmpf is custom "less" operator function used to sort but i never in my life seen comparison functions like that.

Please gurus of c++ decode those two masterpieces, please!

Comment: `rect*`  is pointer on `rect`, not a multiplication.

Comment: `cmpf` is an array of pointer of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rect* test= new rect*[n];
```

is equivalent to

```
 using rectPtr = rect*; // rect pointer 
rectPtr test = new RectPtr[n]; // allocate n pointers.
```

For the second snippet:

```
bool (*cmpf[])(rect_xywhf*, rect_xywhf*)
```

is equivalent to

```
using Fun = bool(rect_xywhf*, rect_xywhf*); // Function type
using FunPtr = Fun*; // pointer on function.
FunPtr cmpf[] // Array of pointer on function
```